# Cloud Run returning 503 when streaming webm video

Tags: google-cloud-run

I'm trying to send a webm video stream over http from Cloud Run to a browser, but it consistently returns a `503` with the message `Service Unavailable`.  Other requests return normally, so the service isn't actually unavailable.  The response comes almost immediately, so it doesn't appear to be a timeout.  The response headers don't carry over my content type (`video/webm`) but rather `text/plain`.  The console logs spit out this error:

> The request failed because either the HTTP response was malformed or
> connection to the instance had an error.

The server and client behave entirely correctly on localhost.  I understand there's a 15 minute maximum on requests with Cloud Run.  I also inferred based on [this blog post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-now-supports-http-grpc-server-streaming) from a few months ago that I'd be able to stream video:

> Here are some example use cases for server-side HTTP streaming:
>
> - **Streaming large files (such as videos) from your serverless applications**
> - Long-running calculations that can report using a progress indicator
> - Batch jobs that can return intermediate or batched responses

I've tried other video container formats (e.g., `flv`) as well as setting the `Content-Length` to maximum (`Long.MAX_VALUE`) or not setting it at all.  However, given it works locally and the error I see in the logs, I'm inclined to believe that Cloud Run (or some layer in between) is balking at the response itself rather than passing it through.  Is there something I'm missing about what Cloud Run expects?

Comment: I had a similar problem, it was a coding environment issue. What is your development environment?

Comment: @Morfinismo I'm using Ktor in Kotlin, overriding `WriteChannelContent` to send data I'm streaming out of ffmpeg.  This is working locally, just not in Cloud Run – my hypothesis is that I'm doing something Cloud Run doesn't like, or not doing something it expects.

Comment: Locally, are you using windows, mac or linux? And have you run the container locally or just the code?

Comment: Well now I feel dumb – I made sure ffmpeg was available for Alpine, but never actually added it to my Dockerfile.  I've got it working now :)  Thanks for pointing me to the obvious @Morfinismo!  If you want to respond with an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. You should answer your own question providing details. That might help someone else in the future. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using transfer-encoding: chunked ?

Comment: I wasn't previously, but I just made sure that header is going through now; it still worked locally, but did not get through Cloud Run.  It gave the same `503` with the same error in the console logs.